# visual studio 2013 error on installation microsoft.net framework 4.51

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a problem while installing vs 2013 the image below shows the error:

[image: error on installation]

I have researched much on Google, on I found that on windows 8.1 the .net framework 4.5.1 is already part of the OS now. When VS 2013 is trying to install .net framework 4.5.1, then the error shows.

Below is the installation log.

```
[10B0:0ED0][2014-01-17T10:28:09]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Process returned error: 0x13ec
[10B0:0ED0][2014-01-17T10:28:09]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: netfxfullredist_43 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 537088000  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 17207296
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x800713EC Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147019796 (0x800713EC), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=netfxfullredist_43
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]i319: Applied execute package: netfxfullredist_43, result: 0x800713ec, restart: None
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to execute EXE package.
[10B0:0ED0][2014-01-17T10:28:09]i351: Removing cached package: netfxfullredist_43, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5934DD101414BBC0B7F1EE2780D2FC8B9BEC5C4D\
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 1984294912  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 1394323456
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 142855262208 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 142855262208 bytes
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[1438:1C98][2014-01-17T10:28:09]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x800713ec, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a language issue.  Are you trying to a version of Visual Studio that is for a different locale than your version of Windows 8.  I only ask because the dialog is telling you don't have the Asia version of 4.5.1 installed.

Comment: i downloaded it as an ISO not sure of the locale issue but i downloaded the 4.5.1 asia .net it says that it is already installed il double check and get back to you

Comment: should i revert back to the original locale?i am from the Philippines but when i installed the vs 2013 before the upgrade happened vs 2013 is working just fine but silly of me of installing cc cleaner then vs 2013 suddenly popping out errors so i tried to re install but the aforementioned error shows

Comment: and may i add i successfully installed it on a win server 2008 r2 sp1 machine

Comment: I've seen the same "Error code 0x800713ec-Asia" installing the .NET fmwk 4.7.2 targeting pack.

Answer (score 2):

In general this seems an issue during NetFx 4.51 install. Try to install NetFX 4.5.1 manually from http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40779. If issues still occur try to google for netfxfullredist_43 and try to solve issues around these searching results.

Or interestingly just got an issue 0x800713ec: In that case. root partition of HDD too full. Here NetFX 4.5.1 needs much space ;-)

Comment: i am trying to install it on drive d: which have 300gb space free i tried installing it manually but the installer says the .net framework is already installed

Answer (score 1):

If netFX 4.5.1 says installed what does then the VS 2013 Ultimate installer bring up for an issue? It should then be another one as the above mentioned one.

In general the root partition also needs much free space. Not sure how much VS Ultimate needs, but assume at least something like 2 GB ++

Answer (score 1):

I installed .Net 4.5.1 and retired installing Visual Studio and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I my case it failed because of very high screen resolution.

.net framework seems need to check the ui status and high resolution may corrupted this.

I was using windows 7 under a parallels desktop virtual machine, and the host macbook enabled full resolution which is larger than 1080p for windows without retina support.

The solution is to Resize the Parallels Desktop to scale down the resolution.

Comment: my laptop has a large screen 1920 x 1080 is my resolution

Comment: i don't know how but finally it was installed but from what i see recent updates from windows may have help