# visual studio 2013 update 4 installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I am really in trouble please help me...vs 2013 not installing..![enter image description here][1]

i got fatal error while installing .net 4.5.1

i have vsultimate 2013 in iso format...
i have these errors..

1. VisualStudio core features User cancelled installation.
2. Fatal error during installation. in microsoft 4.5.1

LOG FILE 
0380:1724][2015-03-24T22:52:44]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[0380:1724][2015-03-24T22:52:44]i000: MUX:  Format Message Failed: 317
[0380:1724][2015-03-24T22:52:44]i399: Apply complete, result: 0xc0000421, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

Answer (score 0):

Try look here, look at the comments maybe related to different locale or display size.

[visual studio 2013 error on installation microsoft.net framework 4.51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176866/visual-studio-2013-error-on-installation-microsoft-net-framework-4-51)