# "Error 0x800713ec - Asia" when Installing .NET Framework 4.7.2 targeting pack

Tags: .net, .net-4.7.2

I downloaded and tried to install the .NET Framework 4.7.2 Targeting Pack. When the downloaded installer runs it produces this error for unknown reasons:

[image]

Note that I am in the USA and have not downloaded an Asia-specific installer (AFAIK), so that part of the error makes no sense to me. The computer I'm installing on has unmodified English / US settings. It is running Windows 7 in a virtual machine.

---

The first lines of the log file which appear to show errors are:

```
[11C8:0AB4][2018-12-11T07:27:41]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Process returned error: 0x13ec
[11C8:0AB4][2018-12-11T07:27:41]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1228:1730][2018-12-11T07:27:41]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
```

---

I've found a similar posting on a MSFT forum but without any solution:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/367071/microsoft-net-framework-472-developer-pack-install.html

There are also some other failures installing other things with similar errors:

- https://github.com/patrickmoore/Mu/issues/7
- [visual studio 2013 error on installation microsoft.net framework 4.51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176866/visual-studio-2013-error-on-installation-microsoft-net-framework-4-51)

But no definitive solution that I can see.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem was: not enough disk space.**

The disk wasn't full but was running low, so I made some room and then it installed OK.

I inferred this from reading about other similar errors, though none specific to .NET framework components. *Therefore this is probably the cause of many cases of `“Error 0x800713ec - Asia"` even in other circumstances.*

I have no idea why such a meaningless error is used, or why the logs are so unclear as well.

Comment: I have the same error but I still have 25 GB of free space in my disk. So there must be other causes.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was able to install it successfully after restart the machine.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error on Windows Server 2008 R2, installing from a shared drive.
The server had plenty of free space.

I moved the .exe to a local path and tried again. This time it worked.